# HTML Table multi column filtering

Tags: html, html-table, filtering

I am working on developing a multi-column multi-word filtering search and have difficulties with two problems:

1. I am only able to partially filter the first column; partial because typing apple it shows apple and oranges in the first column.
2. I am struggling with finding a way to make this a multi-word search over both columns.

I found [a table filtering techniques on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581267/searching-columns-html-table) and <kbd>[adjusted them in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trNV2/49/)</kbd>. But this code will only filter over all the columns with one word. Typing more than one word to narrow the result (find `A and B`) does not work.

The code below is my attempt to perform a multi-column multi-word search in a single box <kbd>[see my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/1841/)</kbd>.

#### How can I achieve filtering over multiple columns that combines the search phrases?

Meaning show only rows where  `searchphrase-1 and searchphrase-2` are present.

JS

```
var $orig_rows1 = $('#table tbody tr td[class = "col1"]');
var $orig_rows2 = $('#table tbody tr td[class = "col2"]');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
   var $rows1 = $orig_rows1;
   var $rows2 = $orig_rows2;
   var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;
    $("tr:hidden").show();
    $rows1.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).parent("tr").hide();
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search title 1">    
<table class="table-striped" id="table">
     <thead>
     <th>Title 1</th>
     <th>Title 2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
   <tr>
      <td class="col1">Apple</td>
      <td class="col2">Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="col1">Grapes</td>
      <td class="col2">Green</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>    
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mistake in your code `</tbody>` is placed wrong*, **it must be**

```
<tbody>    
   <tr>
      <td class="col1">Apple</td>
      <td class="col2">Green</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="col1">Grapes</td>
      <td class="col2">Green</td>
   </tr>    
   <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

*Not a **perfect solution**, suggestions would be greatly appreciated*

Try this <kbd>***[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/1847/)***</kbd> it has multiple words search capability made using [Tag-it! plugin](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html?tags=bhavik&tags=xyz&tags=js).

---

*Update* search for both **AND** and **OR**

<kbd>***[Demo Fiddle with a check box to perform both operations](http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/1857/)***</kbd>

#### Edit: pieces of linked fiddle added

This is a part of the code from the linked fiddle

```
var search = function () {
    if ($('.tagit-label').length) {

        $("#table tbody tr").hide();
        var toShow = [];

        $('.tagit-label').each(function () {
            filter = $(this).text();
            $("#table tbody tr").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) > 0) {
                    toShow.push($("#table tbody tr").index(this));
                }
            });
        });

        if ($('#chkBoth').prop("checked") && $('.tagit-label').length > 1) {
            var filterShow = [];
            var outputArray = [];
            $(toShow).each(function (i, value) {
                if (($.inArray(value, outputArray)) == -1) {
                    outputArray.push(value);
                }
            });
            $(outputArray).each(function (i, value) {
                var index = toShow.indexOf(value);
                toShow.splice(index, 1);
            });
        }

        $(toShow).each(function (i, value) {
            $("#table tbody tr").eq(value).fadeIn();
        });

    } else {
        $("#table tbody tr").fadeIn();
    }
}
```

This is the result of my linked fiddle below:

[image: Result of multi column filter]

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: Hey Bhavik, Your demo filtering is working. However, the logic issue I am having with your filtering method is how it filters multiple words. For example, if I want only rows with "apple" and "1" your Demo gives two rows where it finds all rows with "apple" or "1". Do you know how to adjust your code so that it filters based on the logical operator OR when filtering more than one string? Meaning when I type "apple" and "1" the filtering result should show only one row based on this Demo.

Comment: I found your solution good and i like the tag-it plugin but adding complexity to a demo and not including the relevant parts of your javascript is not ideal for an answer. So if you do not mind i will add the search bit from your code to your answer.

Comment: After reviewing your code, I am not able to discern the .tagit-label . Is this a key word in the Tag-it plugin?

Comment: great, but how to use it on table filled with `Ajax` ?!! cause I tried to apply it , but it gives me wrong result